# Comparing patches

Tags: netlogo

I want to compare the patches in a certain radius regarding the amount of a certain class of agents on them. The agents should move to the patch where the most agents (in this case humans) are. If they are already on the patch with the most humans then they must not move. I coded it and the humans group but most of them don't stay and run around in lines (one behind the other). Would be great if anyone of you could have a quick look at my code. Thanks

```
if Strategy = "Gathering-Simple" [

    if ((count(humans-on max-one-of patches in-radius rad [count(humans-here)] )) ) >= count(humans-here) [
    if count(humans-on patches in-radius rad) - count(humans-here) > 0 [


      face max-one-of patches in-radius rad [count(humans-here)]
    fd 1
    ]]
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a complete working example that uses your code. Is this displaying the behaviour you mean? It does have turtles chasing each other.

```
to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 100 [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  let rad 5
  ask turtles
  [ let target-patch max-one-of patches in-radius rad [count turtles-here]
    if count turtles-on target-patch >= count turtles-here              ; comment 1
    [ if count turtles-on patches in-radius rad > count turtles-here    ; comment 2
      [ face target-patch
        forward 1
      ]
    ]
  ]
  tick
end
```

If so, have a look at the two lines I have comments on.

Comment 1: The >= means that, even if the turtles are already on the highest count patch, this condition will be satisfied because `count turtles-here` will be equal to the count of the turtles on the highest count patch (this patch).

Comment 2: This line means that as long as there are any turtles on any patch within the radius but not on the particular patch where the asking turtle is located, then the turtle will move forward.

If you want to only have turtles move if not on a maximum count patch, try this instead:

```
to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 100 [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  let rad 5
  ask turtles
  [ let target-patch max-one-of patches in-radius rad [count turtles-here]
    if count turtles-on target-patch > count turtles-here
    [ face target-patch
      forward 1
    ]
  ]
  tick
end
```

I took out the = in the comment 1 line and removed the second condition entirely so now the turtles move if their current patch has fewer (strictly, not <=) turtles than the patch they've spotted.

Comment: Thanks a lot JenB! That makes a lot of sense. Didn't know about the target-command! :-)

Comment: There is no target- command. I created a temporary variable called target-patch to store the patch with maximum number of turtles.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the previous post, but have some additional information.

If you want to move entirely **to** the target patch on each iteration, instead of moving just one step **towards** the target patch,  in the above answer you could replace the code which produces one step of motion

```
[ face target-patch
  forward 1
]
```

with

```
 [ 
    move-to target-patch
 ]
```

I confirmed by experimentation that the results of the two methods of moving will produce similar but somewhat different results.

Comment: Thank you. Yes the move-to command comes in handy but in my example the turtles aren't allowed to move more than 1 / tick